# Snippet editor pushed partly offscreen when developer tools side panel opened

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I frequently find myself in the situation where I start editing a Stack Snippet, then open developer tools, which I like to have anchored on the right of the browser window. As soon as I do this, it shoves the left hand side of the editor off the side of the page:

[image]

If I close the snippet editor and reopen it, it recalculates and fits correctly. However I often don't want to do this because I'm halfway through an experimental edit and I don't necessarily want to update the main editor contents (or discard my changes).

I use Chrome most of the time, but I just verified the same happens in the latest Safari and Firefox (all on OS X).

EDIT: I originally thought the editor handled resizing correctly otherwise, but it looks like it's a general issue with window resizes.